# Question about ln and modulus function

Tags: logarithms

Say we had some equation $x$ = $y$, we can conclude that $|x| = |y|$, for definite, but if we started with $|x| = |y|$, we cannot go and say $x=y$, as there's the possibility that $x=-y$.
This is true, I think.
Now let's look at another situation, where we have $\ln|x+5| = \ln|y|$, in my textbook (A Level Maths year 2 pure, UK specification), the textbook concludes that $y=x+5$, but to me this makes no sense because when we had the $|x| = |y|$ situation we couldn't conclude that $x=y$, so why is it any different when we are using the $\ln(x)$ function?

Comment: Context is critical here.  As you say, if we know nothing further about $x,y$ then all you can say is that $(x+5)=\pm y$.  But I expect that your textbook included further information.  Can you link to it?

Comment: I'll take a picture when I'm home but this question just sprung to mind.

Comment: And of course it could be a careless error in the reference, these certainly do happen.  But I expect that once you look closely you'll find that more was known about $x$ and $y$.

Comment: Ah I've found the solution. It's because of the constant of integration which allows for the ambiguity, as the constant has no fixed sign